# Autofac passing parameter to nested types

Tags: c#, ioc-container, autofac

I am using Autofac as my IoC in my WCF service. I have a situation where I want to pass an object to a nested type (ie a type that is not resolved directly, but when resolving another type). As far as I understood, passing this object as a constructor parameter is the preferred way in Autofac. Here is an example of such a situation.

The nested type:

```
public class EventLogger<T> : IEventLogger<T>
{
    public EventLogger(IRepository<T> repository, User currentUser) { ... }  
}
```

The type I am actually trying to resolve:

```
public class SomeBusinessObject  
{  
    public SomeBusinessObject(IEventLogger<SomeLogEventType> logger, ...) { ... }  
}
```

The registration:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EventLogger<>)).As(typeof(IEventLogger<>));
builder.RegisterType<SomeBusinessObject>();
```

The resolving inside my WCF service operation:

```
var currentUser = GetUserFromServiceContext();  
var bo = lifetimeScope.Resolve<SomeBusinessObject>();
```

How and where should I pass the current user to my logger? Should I assume that the WCF operation has to know that resolving SomeBusinessObject requires to resolve IEventLogger first and pass a resolved instance when resolving SomeBusinessObject? Something like this (pardon me if this does not work, it is just an idea):

```
var currentUser = GetUserFromServiceContext();  
var logger = lifetimeScope.Resolve<IEventLogger<SomeLogEventType>>(new NamedParameter("currentUser", currentUser));  
var bo = lifetimeScope.Resolve<SomeBusinessObject>(new NamedParameter("logger", logger));
```

If this is the solution, what happens if the type is nested deeper? Doesn't that defeat at least some of the purpose of dependency injection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IMHO, I think you're violating one of the principles of IOC in that a component should not need to know about the dependencies of it's dependencies. In your case, the container doesn't know that `SomeBusinessObject` has a dependency on `User`.

That being said, you may be able to leverage Autofac's [Delegate Factories](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories). You could manually register a `Func<User, SomeBusinessObject>` to hide the dependency chain details from the client code:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>));
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EventLogger<>)).As(typeof(IEventLogger<>));
builder.RegisterType<SomeBusinessObject>();

builder.Register<Func<User, SomeBusinessObject>>(c => {
    // Autofac should be able to resolve these Func<> automatically:
    var loggerFactory = c.Resolve<Func<User, IEventLogger<SomeLogEventType>>>();
    var sboFactory = c.Resolve<Func<IEventLogger<SomeLogEventType>, SomeBusinessObject>>();

        // Now we can chain the Funcs:
    return u => sboFactory(loggerFactory(u));
});
```

Now in your client code, you can do:

```
var currentUser = GetUserFromServiceContext();  
var sboFactory = lifetimeScope.Resolve<Func<User, SomeBusinessObject>>();
var bo = sboFactory(currentUser);
```

As an aside, I think the lamba/Func support is what makes Autofac the best IOC container. You can do some crazy powerful things if you know how to compose Funcs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate more on the fact that I am violating the principles of IOC? I agree with you that my last solution is, but I don't know why your answer wouldn't too. I mean, your answer also shows that to build SomeBusinessObject, you need to know that it requires a User.

Comment: My answer is too. :) It's a workaround. But if I had to use the objects as designed, I would do this to at least encapsulate the dependency as best as possible.

Comment: OK, I understand then! :-) And if you had to change the design of the objects? ;-) I am really new to IoC and I haven't really get my head around it yet...

Comment: Well you could consider if there's a way to register the type `User`. I do something similar with `IPrincipal` where I do `builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.User);`

Comment: I see. This means that every time I have a `User` as a parameter, it will be resolved as such?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm not surprised, I didn't explain myself very well... Let's say I have a type `SomeOtherBusinessObject` with a constructor like this: `public SomeOtherBusinessObject(User user, ...)`. When I resolve this type, the `User` will always be the same user, ie the user from the service context, right? This might turn out to be a problem in the long run... I don't think using `IPrincipal` in my business layer makes more sense. Maybe I should just make a new class that inherits from `User` that will represent the authenticated user in my WCF service...

Comment: It won't be necessarily always be the same user. If you register it as `builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<SomeServiceContext>().GetUser())` then that method will be evaluated every time a `User` is requested. Without knowing how your `GetUserFromServiceContext()` is implemented, I can't say whether this works for you. The point is that the lamba function is evaluated every time. Another (contrived) example would be `builder.Register(c => { if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 12) return new AMService() else return new PMService(); }).As<ITimeService>();`

Comment: `GetUserFromServiceContext()` just gets the username of the authenticated user from the service context (`ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name`) and retrieves the corresponding `User` in the database. My problem is that `User` is a pretty generic class and can (and often does) represent something else than the authenticated user. But it won't necessarily be a problem as far as IoC is concerned, and I think we are drifting away from the original issue! ;-)