# Resolve Autofac factory based on multiple constructors

Tags: autofac

Does anybody know what's missing to make this test work? 
It's a pitty that it doesn't work out of the box.

```
class A { }

class B { public B(A a) { } }

class C { public C(B b) { } }

[Test]
public void SuperFactoryResolutionTest()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();            
    builder.RegisterType<B>();
    builder.RegisterType<C>();

    using (var container = builder.Build())
    {
        Assert.DoesNotThrow(() =>
        {
            var factory = container.Resolve<Func<A, C>>();
            var x = factory(new A());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what your goal is.  Why don't you register `A` and then use the container to get an instance of `C`?

Comment: In my scenario A is an instance of TcpClient returned by the TcpListener when client is connected...

Comment: Why not add a constructor `public C(A a) : this(new B(a)) { }` - this makes it clear how to construct a `C` given an `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not supported by Autofac.

You can only pass direct dependencies when calling `Resolve`. So you cannot ad-hoc specify dependencies deep down in the hierarchy chain.

Anyway this is against the inversion of control principle: `C` should only know about `B` and should not know that somewhere an `A` is used by `B`. So when you ask for a `C` you also should not tell which `A` to use.

However you can achieve somewhat similar with manually building the resolution chain:

This is the closest what you can get:

```
var intermediateFactory = container.Resolve<Func<B,C>>();
Func<A, C> factory = 
    a => intermediateFactory(container.Resolve<B>(TypedParameter.From(a)));
var x = factory(new A());
```

Comment: Thanks, but your approach is something that I'm trying to avoid. And, I don't think that this is against the inversion of control principle as I'm not asking for C, I'm asking for a factory Func<A, C>.

Comment: Yes you are asking for factory `Func<A, C>` which means that I have an `A` give me a `C` but the problem is that `C` doesn't know about `A` so does this factory won't work from the Autofac point of view. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741761/autofac-passing-parameter-to-nested-types. However what you also can do that you register your handwritten `Func<A,C>` factory in the container: `builder.RegisterType<Func<A, C>>(c => return a => c.Resolve<Func<B,C>>(c.Resolve<B>(TypedParameter.From(a))));`