# Transitive Func<> factories for Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I need the ability to ask Autofac for a factory function that automatically deals with transitive dependencies. This is hard to explain in plain-text, so here's a test:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class FactoryTests
{
    class A { }

    class B
    {
        public B(A a) => A = a;

        public A A { get; }
    }

    class C { }

    class D
    {
        public D(B b, C c)
        {
            B = b;
            C = c;
        }

        public B B { get; }
        public C C { get; }
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<A>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<B>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<C>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<D>().AsSelf();
        var container = builder.Build();

        var transitiveFactory = container.Resolve<Func<A, C, D>>();

        var a = new A();
        var c = new C();
        var instance = transitiveFactory.Invoke(a, c);
        instance.Should().NotBeNull();
        instance.C.Should().BeSameAs(c);
        instance.B.A.Should().BeSameAs(a);
    }
}
```

Currently, the very last line fails.

Basically, I want to get a service that itself depends on a complex tree of other services, but I want to provide the instances to use for one (or more) services in that tree.

How would I go about that? If it's relevant, I'm on the latest version.

UPDATE:
as pointed out by @nemesv in the comments, the solution described in [Can Autofac delegate factories pass parameters to nested objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497640/can-autofac-delegate-factories-pass-parameters-to-nested-objects) works for this scenario here, too.

Comment: Can you check these two questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497640/can-autofac-delegate-factories-pass-parameters-to-nested-objects https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741761/autofac-passing-parameter-to-nested-types?

Comment: @nemesv the second one that uses OnPreparing might help me - I'll try and report back :-)

Comment: indeed, that is the solution, @nemesv - thank you!

Comment: if I knew how I can mark a question as duplicate and link to the other one, I'd do that - can you, @nemesv ?